# Get number of elements of array satisfying a list of conditionsin Python/Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have two arrays of the same size N, `array1` and `array2`. You can essentially think of it as a single array with shape (N,2). The entries are all numbers. I have a list of conditions and I want to see how many entries satisfy all these conditions, ideally using vectorization. For example, the conditions might be something like:

1. element in array1 > 2
2. element in array1 < 5
3. element in array2 > 4
4. element in array2 < 7
5. element in array2 divisible by 2

I want to count the number of indices "i" such that array1[i] and array2[i] satisfy all the above conditions. For eg, if

```
array1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
array2 = np.array([3,4,5,6,7])
```

Then the only indice satisfying the above condition would be 3,and thus the number of indices satisfying the constraints would be just 1. I was considering using several `numpy.logical_and`'s, but this looks rather ugly. I didn't know if there was a cleaner way to string together several `and` statements.

Comment: In this case, numpy.logical_and will be your best friend. Even if it doesn't "look pretty", it is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following:

```
x = np.array(array1>2)
y = np.array(array1<5)
z = np.array(x == y)
sum(z)
```

Answer (score 0):

The shortest way would be to use

```py
np.count_nonzero(
    (array1 > 2) &
    (array1 < 5) &
    (array2 > 4) &
    (array2 < 7) &
    (array2 % 2 == 0)
)
```